# Angular Material - Add css to dots in discrete md-slider

Tags: angularjs, slider, angular-material

Is there any way in which i could style the default dots in the `<md-slider  md-discrete>`?[image]
E.g. - If I would want to **increase the size of the dots** to make them visible more distinctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I increased the height of the dots using the following CSS

```
/*Slider Thick marks*/

md-slider .md-track-ticks canvas {
  height: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-ticks-container {
  height: 8px !important;
  top: -3px !important;  
}

.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-ticks {
  height: 8px !important;
}
```